# javascript's substr strange behaviour?

Tags: javascript

I need to extract the date from json :

```
/Date(1224043200000)/
```

I [saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date) That I can do it by :

```
var date = new Date(parseInt('/Date(1224043200000)/'.substr(6))); 
                                    ^
                                    |
------------------------------0123456
```

But how does `substr` knows to ignore the last chars ?
[)/]

I've searched at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) , but couldn't find the documented behaviour.

Comment: It's not `substr` that skips the last non numeric chars, it's `parseInt`. To be on the save side, I'd rather go with the `length` parameter to `substr`.

Comment: Sidenote: to prevent strange behavior always use `parseInt()` with the radix parameter!

Comment: I know ....`parseInt('010')=>8` (octal base)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.substr()` return everything after the 6th char.

But `parseInt()` will parse all numeric chars until it reaches a non numeric char, so the ignoring happens by `parseInt`

---

[**Quoting the docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

> If `parseInt` encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. `parseInt` truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var date = new Date(parseInt('/Date(1224043200000)/'. substring(6, indexOf(")")-1 ));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go about this another way. Gaby explained about parseInt, but a note of caution: `parseInt` interprets integers with leading zeroes as octals. This might not apply in your case, but IMO, this is a safer approach:

```
var date = new Date(+('/Date(1224043200000)/'.match(/\d+/)[0]));
```

First, `'/Date(1224043200000)/'.match(/\d+/)` extracts the numbers from the string, in an array: `["1224043200000"]`.
We then need the first element of these matches, hence the `[0]`. 
To be on the safe side, I wrapped all this in brackets, preceded by a `+` sign, to coerce the matched substring to a number: `+('/Date(1224043200000)/'.match(/\d+/)[0]) === 1224043200000`
This is passed to the `Date` constructor, which creates a date object with `"Wed Oct 15 2008 06:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)"` as a string value

To catch any possible errors, you might want to split this one-liner up a bit, but that's up to you :)